# Can I change what Agent 3 looks like?

Tags: splatoon-2, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

After collecting three thangs in the Octo Expansion, Captain Cuttlefish draws a “missing” poster of Agent 3 to determine their gender, skin color, and eye color.

I wanted to make Agent 3 look like my character from Splatoon 1, but I chose the wrong skin tone and eye color.

Can I change what Agent 3 looks like after Cuttlefish draws the missing poster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Outside of starting over with a new save file, there is no way to change Agent 3's appearance once it has been set.